# Doing range queries in Mongoose for Hour / Day / Month/ Year

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, date-range, range-query, nosql

Trying to figure out how to do this. Basically I want to sort by Hour / Day / Month / Year of my submissions.

Each `submission` has a `created` field which contains a Mongoose Date object in the form of `"created" : ISODate("2013-03-11T01:49:09.421Z")`. Do I need to compare against this in the find() conditions?

Here is my current query (I'm wrapping it in a count for pagination purposes FWIW so just ignore that part):

```
  getSubmissionCount({}, function(count) {

  // Sort by the range
    switch (range) {
      case 'today':
        range = now.getTime();
      case 'week':
        range = now.getTime() - 7;
      case 'month':
        range = now.getTime() - 31; // TODO: make this find the current month and # of   days in it
      case 'year':
        range = now.getTime() - 365;
      case 'default':
        range = now.getTime();
    }

    Submission.find({
      }).skip(skip)
         .sort('score', 'descending')
         .sort('created', 'descending')
         .limit(limit)
         .execFind(function(err, submissions) {
            if (err) {
          callback(err);
        }

        if (submissions) {
          callback(null, submissions, count);
        }
    });
  });
```

Can someone help me figure this out? With that current code it just gives me all submissions regardless of a time range, so I'm obviously not doing something properly

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think, you are looking `$lt`(Less than) and `$gt`(Greater Than) operators in MongoDB.
By using above operators the result can be queried according to time.

I am adding possible solution below.

```
var d = new Date(),
hour = d.getHours(),
min = d.getMinutes(),
month = d.getMonth(),
year = d.getFullYear(),
sec = d.getSeconds(),
day = d.getDate();


Submission.find({
  /* First Case: Hour */
  created: { $lt: new Date(), $gt: new Date(year+','+month+','+day+','+hour+','+min+','+sec) } // Get results from start of current hour to current time.
  /* Second Case: Day */
  created: { $lt: new Date(), $gt: new Date(year+','+month+','+day) } // Get results from start of current day to current time.
  /* Third Case: Month */
  created: { $lt: new Date(), $gt: new Date(year+','+month) } // Get results from start of current month to current time.
  /* Fourth Case: Year */
  created: { $lt: new Date(), $gt: new Date(year) } // Get results from start of current year to current time.
})
```

Comment: Your method is half-way right so I'll accept it. BUT, I needed to do something like: `var now = new Date(), start = new Date(now), start.setDate(start.getDate - numDays)`;