# hide event dates that are older than today in express and mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express, mongoose

I have a rest service that gets all Events stored in a mongodb and sorts them  but how do I not show ones past the current day and time?

```
//return all events
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    Event.find({}, null, {sort: {date: 1}}, function(err, events) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.json(events);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gonna point you to an old thread w/ this

[Querying with mongoose and dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17554943/querying-with-mongoose-and-dates)

Seems to be exactly what you need

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add a `created` (or however you want to name it, `createdAt`, etc.) to your Event model. You can use a function like this to automatically set the date on save:

```
var eventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({...});

eventSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  var currentDate = new Date();
  this.created = currentDate;
  next();
});
```

Put this function right under where you defined your mongoose model.

Then you can use the `$lt` (less than) option supported by MongoDB:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    // Get date of yesterday
    var yesterday = new Date();
    yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate() - 1);
    // Find every event that was created yesterday or the days before.
    Event.find({ created: { $lt: yesterday } }, function(err, events) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.json(events);
    });
});
```

Reference:

- [stackoverflow.com/questions/17554943/querying-with-mongoose-and-dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17554943/querying-with-mongoose-and-dates)
- [stackoverflow.com/questions/17008683/doing-range-queries-in-mongoose-for-hour-day-month-year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17008683/doing-range-queries-in-mongoose-for-hour-day-month-year)

Comment: you might want to change the Date yesterday a bit. As it is now it will exclude events from the last 24h.  
FYI there is also the `$gt` (greater than) option.